# foreign keys incongruity to save in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, database-design, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

[image: database design]

I have this problem when I create phps with cake bake In cakephp.I have the following problem:
if I keep **two elements in libraries**, one with id 1 and othe id 2.then I saved an item in **rooms with library_id= 1**,and after another item in **rooms with library_id= 2**. I really can relate **room element with the element of user**. This should not afford it since they have the same library_id.So it does not refer to the same library. I need only user can relate to room if they refer to the same library.**I try that cakephp throws error, or do not allow the relationship, when users and rooms not have the same library_id,how I can do this?**

**result tables:**

```
libraries         users               rooms                 users_rooms
id            id   library_id       id   library_id        user_id   room_id
1             1       1             1       2                1           1
2
```

Comment: this makes very little sense. What are your cake model associations, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The description is a lot easier to read now, but it's not clear what the actual question/problem is; obviously if you have a `rooms_users` table - it's possible to associate rooms to users. with the schema you've put in the question it's not possible to enforce via referencial integrity such that users and rooms must belong to the same library.

Comment: I need only user can relate to room if they refer to the same library. how I can do this?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I try in cakephp throws error, or do not allow the relationship, when users try to connect rooms and're not the same library_id

Answer (score 1):

> I need only user can relate to room if they refer to the same library. how I can do this?

Normally, diamond-shaped dependencies where the two "sides" of the diamond must lead from the "bottom" to the **same** "root", require the usage of identifying relationships:

[image]

Note how `library_id` is migrated from the "root", down both "sides" of the diamond and then **merged** at the "bottom" in the `users_rooms` table. This way, if an user is connected to a room, they both must be connected to the same library.

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with CakePHP so I can't tell whether it supports this.

Comment: thanks anyway! Had thought of something, but I can not work for me Because cakephp complaining about library_id  in users_rooms